# Centering y-axis label

Tags: tikz-pgf

The question is, how to vertically align the label to the middle of the y-axis. It seems that the code above first rotate the label and then move it above. The complete example is pasted below.

The code in question is:

```
\node[rotate=90, above=1] at (y axis mid) {long label};
```

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid[xstep=1.5,ystep=1] (6,6);

% Axis
\draw[->,>=latex'] (0,0) -- coordinate (x axis mid) (6.5,0);
\draw[->,>=latex'] (0,0) -- coordinate (y axis mid) (0,6.5);

% Labels
\node[below=0.2] at (x axis mid) {long label};
\node[rotate=90,above=1] at (y axis mid) {long label};

\draw[red,very thick] (0,0) -- (0,3) -- (3,3) -- (3,6) -- (6,6);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: change `above=1` to `yshift=10pt` will center the y label.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest is to put the node while drawing axes:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid[xstep=1.5,ystep=1] (6,6);
\draw[->,>=latex'] (0,0) -- node[pos=0.5,below,rotate=0]{long label} (6.5,0);
\draw[->,>=latex'] (0,0) -- node[pos=0.5,above,rotate=90]{long label} (0,6.5);
\draw[red,very thick] (0,0) -- (0,3) -- (3,3) -- (3,6) -- (6,6);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can control the spacing and distance (between axis and label) by `pos=<dimen>` and `above/below=<dimen>` respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Use `above` alone. Here `yshift==xx` works well too.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,calc,arrows,positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid[xstep=1.5,ystep=1] (6,6);
% Axis
\draw[->,>=latex'] (0,0) -- coordinate (x axis mid) (6.5,0);
\draw[->,>=latex'] (0,0) -- coordinate (y axis mid) (0,6.5);
% Labels
\node[below=0.2] at (x axis mid) {long label};
\node[rotate=90,yshift=10pt] at (y axis mid) {long label}; % Or use above alone.

\draw[red,very thick] (0,0) -- (0,3) -- (3,3) -- (3,6) -- (6,6);
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```